# Can I execute a file in the Godot package with godots OS.execute?

Tags: godot

I have a python file in my godot game thats executed by [OS.execute](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-execute).

```
OS.Execute("python3", new String[3] { "scripts/myScript.py"}, true, output);
```

This doesn't work anymore in the exported version as the path is not valid anymore. Also, doing `res://scripts/myScript.py` does not work.

How can I execute my script in the exported version?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with other files and I solved it including with the executable a folder with the file with the same names I have at the project.
Try to make this tree in your exported project:

```
ExportFolder
    |
    *-- Program.exe
    *-- Program.pck
    *-- scripts
            |
            *-- myScript.py
```

At this point, you can use myScript.py as a resource (res://).